# How can you run a remote GWT application in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, virtual-machine

I have a GWT project on my VM (it uses maven) it's not hosted on google servers.
I've imported it using eclipse's "Remote Services" but cannot launch it as a gwt app.

is there a way to do this in eclipse (or another IDE)?

Answer (score 0):

You need the gwt eclipse plugin as well as the maven gwt plugin.

Here you find a detailed explanation how to set that up: http://uptick.com.au/content/getting-started-gwt-maven-and-eclipse